# play song in fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

Hello in my project I am to play a song when I click on a button and this button is is a fragment layout but I don't now if I need to put the code in the fragment or in the MainActivity. So here I put it in the fragment and the **"protected"** of the `protected void` is underline in red same for the "(this, resId)". Can someone help thanks a lot.

here is my **fragment.java**

```
public class thekairi78 extends Fragment {

private AdView adView;
private MediaPlayer mPlayer = null;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.thekairi78, container,
            false);



    Button regarde = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.regarde);
    regarde.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            playSound(R.raw.regarde);
        }
    });


    adView = new AdView(getActivity());
    adView.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111");
    adView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.layout_admob);
    layout.addView(adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
    return rootView;





}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    if(mPlayer != null && mPlayer.isPlaying()){
        mPlayer.pause();
    }
    super.onPause();

}

private void playSound(int resId){
    if (mPlayer != null) {
        mPlayer.stop();
        mPlayer.release();

    }
    mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, resId);
    mPlayer.start();
}

}
```

and here my **MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private MediaPlayer mPlayer = null;



    private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;


    private ViewPager mViewPager;

    InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;
    private InterstitialAd interstitial;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();


        interstitial = new InterstitialAd(MainActivity.this);

        interstitial.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.admob_interstitial_id));

        interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);

        interstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            public void onAdLoaded() {

                displayInterstitial();
            }
        });



        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());


        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);


    }




    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }


 public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {

            switch (position)  {
                case 0:
                  thekairi78 tab1 = new thekairi78();

                    return tab1;
                case 1:
                  kenny tab2 = new kenny();
                    return tab2;
                case 2:
                    autres tab3 = new autres();
                    return tab3;
                default:
                    return null;
            }


        }



        @Override
        public int getCount() {

            return 3;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return "TheKairi78";
                case 1:
                    return "Kenny";
                case 2:
                    return "Autres SoundBox";
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    public void displayInterstitial() {

        if (interstitial.isLoaded()) {
            interstitial.show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        if(mPlayer != null && mPlayer.isPlaying()){
            mPlayer.pause();
        }
        super.onPause();

    }


    private void playSound(int resId){
        if (mPlayer != null) {
            mPlayer.stop();
            mPlayer.release();

        }
        mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, resId);
        mPlayer.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Which protected is underlined, and what does the error say?

Comment: The protected of the void onPause and it say ; Error:(62, 20) error: onPause() in thekairi78 cannot override onPause() in Fragment
attempting to assign weaker access privileges; was public